# share one or more variables to ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to pass only one variable from a js file to ejs file.

I know about `app.locals.Variable` and about using `<% include (./app.js) %>` in the ejs file.

But , I don't want to include the whole app.js , only the specific one or more variables.

Answer (score 0):

If using Express?

```
res.render('ejsfile', {
    variable_for_ejs: source_of_variable
});
```

Comment: :This requires to be executed from example `app.get('/ejsdile'),{ ...`.But I already have other res.renders.How can I do what you say ?(if possible)

Comment: Can you provide more code so we can see the request and response

Comment: :It's not something specific.Just , in an app.js I would have a lot of functions and  res.renders in each.So, I am not sure how to use yours.Isn't another way to accomplish this?Thakns